# How to set by OS not installed font in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

We are using SF Pro font, free font provided by Apple. If font is installed on my or the users computer, then it will be used when loading of our website.

We have styles like:

```css
.public-url {
    font-family: SFPro-Regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #57606a;
}
```

But if font is not installed on computer, then fallback font is used. How can I avoid using fallback font and use `SF Pro`?

I put font into project folder `/public/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf` and created this in global.css.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SFPro-Regular';
    src: url(/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf);
    font-display: swap;
}
```

But if I remove In my Mac the installed `SF Pro` font, browser will not load it. Why?

Tried this also:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: SFPro;
    src: url(/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Comment: So the browser should in the network tab create a request to load the font for the use of the page, does this happen?

Comment: Should it not be like this in the .public-url, font-family: "SFPro-Regular", SFPro-Regular;